# Restrict access to HTML/CSS/IMG or root index folders?

Tags: javascript, html, css, root

Is there any simple way to remove the ability for someone to download the html/css/img folders from the index site? I'm new to this so this may be a dumb question! Also, do robots.txt play any role in this?

Thanks!

Comment: If the content of your html/css/img folders are accessible over the internet then they are also downloadable. This has nothing to do with `robots.txt` which is for defining which files and folders visiting robot/web-crawlers should or should not index.

Comment: There is no effective way to protect your file (css, js, images) from being downloaded. If so, then Big companies gonna lock all of the file as example (facebook, google)

Comment: The browser needs to access these files in order to render your site correctly. If the browser can access them, the user can also download/save them. Nothing to do about this, that is just the nature of the internet. And no, robots.txt has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a index file which just does a `header(location)`redirect the user.

Or make an `.htaccess` file in that folder and add this:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://mysite/
```

the link is where the user will be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume what you want it's to prevent hotlinking, if you are using an [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) Server, you have to make use of [.htacess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) file. Maybe something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Check out this [how-to](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-mod_rewrite-hot-linking-images-leeching-howto/).

Or [this one](http://www.nginxtips.com/how-to-stop-image-hotlinking-on-nginx/) if you are using [nginx](http://nginx.org/http://httpd.apache.org/)